# Custom Search on Cell instance for material-react-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

I have this column definition:

```
 const columns = useMemo ((d) => [
{
  accessorFn: (r) => r,
  Cell: ({ renderedCellValue  }) => {
    const r = renderedCellValue;
      if(r.req_for != null){
        if(r.req_for.add_contact === null){
           return <span><b>{r.req_for.add_type.add_type_code}</b>, {r.req_for.add_section.add_sec_name}</span>
         }else {
           return <span><b>{r.req_for.add_contact.add_cont_name}</b>, {r.req_for.add_contact.add_cont_position}</span>
         }}
  },
header: 'Request For',
size: 200,
},
...
```

and material react object

```
<MaterialReactTable
      columns={columns}
      data={userRequests}
      enableColumnFilterModes
      enableColumnOrdering
      enableRowSelection
      enableRowActions
      enableGlobalFilter
/>
```

However the data of this cell does not appear in search and when i search data produced by above code it shows that there is "no records".

a conditional accessorKey is possible would solve the problem.